# React Vite: Exports from local modules not found (Migration from CRA)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, vite, es6-modules

I am trying to import exported members from local nodejs packages. These worked fine before using Vite (standard CRA webpack setup), but ever since switching to Vite, I am getting the following error:

```css
Uncaught SyntaxError:
The requested module '/@fs/Users/...{long_path}.../lib/shared/countries/build/index.js' 
does not provide an export named 'countryListAllIsoData'
```

The Vite project was setup using `npm create vite@latest` using the **typescript**, react, swc preset.
These failed imports only happen on local packages (none installed from the npm registery) so I am sure the issue is on my end, but I have not been able to track down what is causing it.

### Question 1: How can I make these imports work?

As they did work using Webpack, I'm not quite sure why they don't work using Vite? Vite required my project to setup the project as a module (in `package.json` - `"type": "module"`). Does the way imports work in a module break my current code?

### Question 2: How can I make my linter display these errors?

I am using VS Code which seems to be perfectly happy with the way the module is imported. No errors are shown and I can go to the definition of the imports without any problems (leading me to believe everything is exported correctly).

### Relevant code snippets

I am importing as follows:

```js
import { countryListAllIsoData } from "countries";
```

The `tsconfig.json` file is untouched (exactly as `npm create vite@latest` created). The same applies for the `package.json` file, except some modules were installed (e.g. the one causing this issue).

The local package causing this issue is named `countries` and is fairly small and simple. It has the following `package.json` file:

```json
/// package.json
{
  "name": "countries",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./build/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Bram Vanbilsen",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */

    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    "outDir": "./build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

The `index.ts` file:

```js
export const countryListAllIsoData = [...] as const;
```

Comment: Any resolution to this? Experiencing the same issue, very frustrating...
The only way we have been able to resolve (to keep work moving forward) is to change the import in code:
import {something} from "../../../../../../{some long path}/src/index". Definitely doesn't work as you describe from the package.json. But all seems fine once we push to registry...

Comment: @Telegard I unfortunately never found a solution other than the long path “solution” mentioned. Not sure whether this is a bug or whether some config is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

### The issue

I have faced the same issue and was able to resolve it.

The problem is that vite, in contrast to e.g. webpack, needs ESM modules to work since this is the primary reason Vite is so fast compared to other bundlers. By this - and some other - reason(s) Vite will pre-bundle dependencies and perform a conversion from UMD or CommonJS modules to ESM modules.

Quoted from [Vite docs - Dependency pre-bundling](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#dependency-pre-bundling):

> CommonJS and UMD compatibility: During development, Vite's dev serves all code as native ESM. Therefore, Vite must convert dependencies that are shipped as CommonJS or UMD into ESM first.

However, Vite does not perform this conversion for linked (local) dependencies. Therefore you have to make sure you are only using ESM modules.

### Solution #1

To resolve the issue you need to change the `tsconfig.json` of your library syntax to use ESM modules, so `"module"` MUST NOT be `commonjs`, but should e.g. be `ES6` or `ESNext` etc.. You also need to adjust the `"moduleResolution"` to `ES6`, `ESNext` or for TypeScript >= 5.x.x `Bundler`.

So your `tsconfig.json` should look like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    "module": "ESNext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */

    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    "outDir": "./build",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

### Solution #2:

Quoted from [Vite docs - Monorepos and Linked Dependencies](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#monorepos-and-linked-dependencies):

---

In a monorepo setup, a dependency may be a linked package from the same repo. Vite automatically detects dependencies that are not resolved from `node_modules` and treats the linked dep as source code. It will not attempt to bundle the linked dep, and will analyze the linked dep's dependency list instead.

However, this requires the linked dep to be exported as ESM. If not, you can add the dependency to `optimizeDeps.include` and `build.commonjsOptions.include` in your config.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['linked-dep'],
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [/linked-dep/, /node_modules/],
    },
  },
})
```

When making changes to the linked dep, restart the dev server with the `--force` command line option for the changes to take effect.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, it still doesn't solve my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366247/error-occurs-when-from-npm-and-not-when-in-local-vite-directory-import-is-not-s

I'd be glad if you can point me to something to read about.
There's a reproduction of my case here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6sixhn?file=main.js
That I described here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14769

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and using Vite aliases fixed it.

In the Vite config, add an alias for the package names with absolute paths to the local folder:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {"countries":"/Users/...{long_path}.../lib/shared/countries"}
}
```